# Server Error | TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'enumTypes')

Tags: typescript, next.js, prisma

I'm new using Next.js, TypeScript and Prisma. My project has been running properly and somehow today when I'm running it again this error happend.

[image: error]

Here is my db.ts

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

declare global {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-var, no-unused-vars
    var cachedPrisma: PrismaClient;
}

let prisma: PrismaClient;
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    prisma = new PrismaClient();
} else {
    if (!global.cachedPrisma) {
        global.cachedPrisma = new PrismaClient();
    }
    prisma = global.cachedPrisma;
}

export const db = prisma;
```

so what is the problem here, help me please.
And Thanks

I haven't tried anything for now because I don't even understand the error here and I don't yet find explanation for what happen on internet.